# How can I get help for knowing if a question already exists?

Tags: support, search

Is there a place or a forum or a chat where I can search and get help for finding if a question already exists?

I have a question like

> "I need to remove a multi-line text (contained in a file) from another text file but only the first occurrence"

I have saved the text of the question here - https://pastebin.com/WKeUGNVm

I am afraid to ask this question because it might already exist and it gets closed and that is bad for my reputation - if too many of my questions get closed then I can get banned from posting questions.

Comment: You don't really need this. If you've put forth a good faith effort to find existing questions, using both Google's site search *and* Stack Overflow's built-in search, but still come up with nothing, then you should go ahead and ask. Only you know if your efforts were truly good faith or not, but if they were, you should have no shame whatsoever in asking. Even if it a form of the question *has* been asked before, it'll be using different keywords that you likely couldn't have known without already knowing the answer, and thus your duplicate question will serve as a useful signpost to it.

Comment: Note that, if you were to ask a question like this, you'd need to specify a programming environment. Your PasteBin doesn't say anything about that. In fact, it's not even clear from the PasteBin that this is a programming question, within the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: As long as you show your research(links and what you've tried), you should be good even if it is a duplicate- The research will speak for itself.

Comment: @Spectric That's neither easy nor effective. Asking a good question is difficult, and it takes time to compose one that is suitable to post. Furthermore, Stack Overflow gets an extremely large number of questions per day, so the mere fact that a question is not noted as a duplicate doesn't mean that it isn't one. It is *strongly suggested* that the asker perform some research effort first, before asking the question. Joking or not, please do not suggest that people skip that step. It doesn't do us or them any good.

Comment: I asked another question, it was closed for not doing enough research, Later I posted a complicated solution that I could invent but it is still closed. I don't know how much research I need to do in order to be considered enough. Now I posted another pastebin with my question, it contains the similar questions that I could find and the complicated and not-really-usable solution that I could find - https://pastebin.com/ppZCKd0r

Comment: "Not doing enough research" is not a close reason.

Comment: It says it needs more clarity but the question is really clear, I gave a clear example of what I need the script to do. Aso someone posted in a comment that it does not contain enough research, I assumed it was closed for not doing enough research - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65513225/remove-lines-after-match

Comment: "*It says it needs more clarity but the question is really clear, I gave a clear example of what I need the script to do*" you gave out a work task for somebody else to do for you. That was the first version of your question. It was was closed because of it. Avoid just giving out assignments and show what you've tried.